# Connection to a db with Doctrine pdo_sqlsrv

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.2, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to connect to my database in SQL Server 2000, but i get an error

> could not find driver

when i'm using pdo_sqlsrv.
But if i use sqlsrv i get an error

> Attempted to call function "sqlsrv_configure" from namespace
>   "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv".

Here is my config.yml

config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname: "%database_name%"
                user: "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                host: "%database_host%"
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                charset:  utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            connection2:
                dbname: "%database_name2%"
                user: "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                host: "%database_host2%"
                driver:  pdo_sqlsrv
                #driver:  sqlsrv  i've also tried this
                #charset:  utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Does anybody know why i'm getting these errors?

Answer (score 5):

If the function sqlsrv_configure can't be found, then the sqlsrv extension isn't installed. It can be found on the official Microsoft repository [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql).

You can check if you've installed the extension by running the command `php -m` in your terminal. Note that if you're running Symfony on a standalone server (eg MAMP, XAMP, or anything else that uses a non-CLI version of PHP) then the extensions used by the CLI and the standalone server may differ.

You can test this by going to the profiler in Symfony (`/_profiler` by default) and clicking on the "View full PHP configuration" link under the `Configuration` menu item. This will open the `phpinfo()` screen. Look for either the `sqlsrv` or `pdo_sqlsrv` extensions there.

**EDIT**

Looking at the [Doctrine docs](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/a7eb74ea296c85a06c324088b2d6e10f6b448fae/docs/en/reference/configuration.rst) again, it seems that `pdo_sqlsrv` causes problems. Doctrine recommends using `sqlsrv`.

> `pdo_sqlsrv`: A Microsoft SQL Server driver that uses `pdo_sqlsrv` PDO **Note that this driver caused problems in our tests. Prefer the sqlsrv driver if possible.**

(Emphasis not mine)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
driver:        pdo_sqlsrv
database_port: 1433
```

Not sure if that will work, but try it.

Comment: Alvin Bunk thank you but doesn't work, i have tried the connection in a different way just to check the parameters are correct and was succeeded, i think the problem is in the driver or i don't know what could be.