# How to connect Symfony 4 with MSSQL

Tags: php, symfony, azure, azure-sql-database, symfony4

Is there any way to configure and connect to MSSQL database using Symfony 4?

I tried to configure Doctrine, but I get the error that I cannot debug. I'd be grateful for any clues.

1. I've put the line below in .env file:

`DATABASE_URL=sqlsrv://myname:mypassword@symfonytest.database.windows.net/AzureDB?port=1433`

Then I run the command in CMD to ping the database and I get the error (I've just hidden the username and password here):
[image]

2. I get the same result when I put the configuration in doctrine.yaml:
   [image]
3. I've added the proper drivers into WAMP.

`Extensions in php.ini:
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll`

WAMP 3.1.0
PHP version: 7.1.9
APACHE 2.4.27

But generally I cannot run my app through WAMP, because something wrong happens with links, so...

4. I run it by running the command in CMD:

php bin/console server:run

And all in all - I get the error like I described.

Sorry for pictures - I was fighting with the SO to put the code here, but it always "appeared as not properly formatted".

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480399 - probably that solves your problem?

Comment: Thanks Nico - I did it and it does not work. Please look again at my post - I've updated it heavily.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this [Azure Distribution Bundle](https://github.com/beberlei/AzureDistributionBundle) to connect Symphony to Azure services.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-php) the official Microsoft documentation to connect to Azure SQL Database from PHP.

Comment: Please give it a try.

Comment: I'm trying:
composer require brainsonic/AzureDistributionBundle
but it gives me an error.
beberlei/AzureDistributionBundle version also gives me the same error.